# Measure Theory: Simple Measure Invariance Proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let M be a metric space, $f: M \rightarrow M$ be a measurable transformation and $\mu$ be a measure on M. Show that $f$ preserves $\mu$ if and only if
$\int \phi d\mu =\int \phi \circ f d\mu$ for every bounded continuous function $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt at a proof:
First prove this direction $\rightarrow$.

We assume that $f \mbox{ preserves } \mu$

I have proved before that If $f:M \rightarrow M$ is a measurable transformation and $\mu$ is a measure on $M$. Then $f$ preserves $\mu$ if and only if $\int \phi d\mu = \int \phi \circ f d\mu$ for every integrable $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. (This was easy to prove).

Thus since bounded continuous functions are dense in $L^1$, (i.e. $C(M) \subset L^1(M,\mu))$.

Now for the other direction. Suppose that $\int\phi d\mu=\int \phi \circ f d\mu$ for every bounded continuous function $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Need to show that $f$ preserves $\mu$, meaning that we need to show that $\mu (E) =\mu(f^{-1}(E))$ for every measurable set $E \subset M$.

**Now, I'm not sure how to show how this, relation holds $\mu (E) =\mu(f^{-1}(E))$ for every measurable set $E \subset M$, where f is a continuous bounded function**.  I know how to do it when $f$ is just a characteristic function (then simple etc..). But, I don't know how to show it is true for arbitrary f that is continuous and bounded.  Do I need to use something with linear functionals or is there a way to do it without that?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your argument  for the first part is not valid. How do you know that bounded continuous functions are dense in $L^{1}(\mu)$ for any Borel measure $\mu$ on any metric space?
2. You have assume that $\mu$ is a finite measure. Otherwise bounded continuous functions may not be integrable.
3. Here is how you can prove this result: let $\nu(E)=\mu (f^{-1}(E))$. This defines another finite measure and what we are asked to prove is that $\mu=\nu$ iff $\int \phi\, d\mu =\int \phi\, d\nu$ for all bounded continuous functions $\phi$. Suppose this equation holds for such $\phi$ and let $C$ be a closed set. For each $n$ let $A_n=\{x\in M: d(x,C) <\frac 1 n\}$; there exists a  continuous function $f_n:M\to[0,1]$ such that $f_n=1$ on $C$ and $f_n(x) =0$ if $x \notin A_n$. Apply the hypothesis with $\phi$ replaced by $f_n$ and let $ n \to \infty$. Note that $f_n \to I_C$ pointwise. Use DCT to conclude that $\mu (C)=\nu (C)$. Thus $\mu$ and $\nu $ coincide on the class of all closed sets. Can you show that $ \mu=\nu$? [ One way is to use the $\pi -\lambda $ theorem].

Comment: Why the downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, it was someone else.

Comment: I upvoted it so it cancels out whoever downvoted it. @Kavi Rama Murthy I'm not familiar with $\pi -\lambda$ theorem. The book gives a hint.  I will update my question with the hints.  The idea, according to the book, is to approximate characteristic functions with continuous functions, using this fact: Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on some metric space M.  For, every integrable function $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence $\phi_n: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, n \geq 1$ of uniformly continuous functions converging to $\phi$ at $\mu$-almost every point.

Comment: I know I didn't prove that bounded continuous functions are dense in $L^1(\mu)$ for any Borel measure $\mu$ on any metric space.  But, this fact is true, right? Or are there cases where this doesn't hold. thanks.

Comment: @kemb The best result that is known is that this property holds for a regular Borel measure on  a locally compact Hausdorff space. My guess is that it is not true in a metric space, but I don't have a counterexample at this time.

Comment: thanks, any thoughts on the hints which I mentioned above.  How do i use the approximation of characteristic functions with continuous functions in the proof as mentioned in the hints above.

Comment: @kemb AS I have done in my answer you first approximate characteristic functions of closed sets  by continuous and then  use  a sigma algebra argument (by which I mean Monotone Class Theorem or $\pi- \lambda$ Theorem. You cannot dierectly handle characteristic functions of Borel sets.

Comment: Last question. Thanks. This for fun by the way, self-learning not for a class. How do you know there exists a  continuous function $f_n:M\to[0,1]$ such that $f_n=1$ on $C$ and $f_n(x) =0$ if $x \notin A_n$? Also, I don't know how why the question that I asked translates to proving $\mu=\nu$ iff $\int \phi d\mu=\int \phi d\nu$ How is this equivalent to the statement  $\int \phi d\mu =\int \phi \circ f d\mu$

Comment: @kemb $f_n(x)=\frac {d(x,A_n )} {d(x,C)+d(x,A_n }$ is such a function. For the last question you have asked just look at the definition  of $\nu$ in my answer.

Comment: Hm I see. It just doesn't seem very intuitive to me. Like I don't believe I could construct such a proof myself. I feel like I am lacking intuition behind each of the steps. Could just tell me quick summary of your proof? thanks